# How to simplify or calculate a formula with very big factorials

Tags: approximation, binomial-coefficients, big-numbers

I'm facing a practical problem where I've calculated a formula that, with the help of some programming, can bring me to my final answer. However, the numbers involved are so big that it takes ages to compute, and I think it might not be necessary. I have the following formula,

$\sum\limits^{k}_{i=m}(N-i)^{k-i}(\frac{1}{N})^k\frac{k!}{(k-i)!i!} \leq a$

from which I need to calculate N. The rest of the values are constants, but in the range of the 100,000s. The factorial there is giving me a headache, since the values involved are too large; what simplifications could I make that will loosen the bounds slightly and thereby simplify the calculation? Are there any standard tricks? Or perhaps a way to calculate this in matlab / octave?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).  It is very accurate for large factorials.

Comment: Stirling's approximation would not help at all. The same restrictions apply for this formula too. What's good with having to calculate 100000 in the exponent?

Comment: @PanosK.:  I don't see any $N!$ there.  The next step would be to use the normal approximation for the $k \choose i$ term

Comment: Yes there are no factorials there indeed. I am talking about computers. It does look better on paper and it's better when i do the calculations. but the complexity, or even better the time and memory needed to compute this number (100000) had no practical implementation in my mobile phone calculator for example. I can calculate max 480! With Stirling's approximation it's exactly the same.

Comment: And don't forget that O(n!) < O(n^n)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to compute the individual factorials in order to compute $k!/(k-i)!i!$, since that's the binomial coefficient $\binom{k}{i}$. A simple algorithm for computing binomial coefficients can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_in_programming_languages). A more sophisticated algorithm is due to Goetgheluck ([JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2323099)); implementations can be found [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/binomial.html) and [here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastBinomialFunction.html).

Of course, with numbers of the size that you have, this might still not be feasible, and in this case I also recommend Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good writeup about implementing Stirling's approximation, along with a reference implementation:

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/stirlings-approximation-formula-clojure/

Answer (score 2):

```
 import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Convenience methods for deterministic combinations.
 * 
 * Usage:
 * <pre> 
 * Factorial f = new Factorial();
 * long ten_over_two = f.over(10,2);     //takes a while, because no cache yet
 * System.out.println( f.factorial( 8)); //instantaneous
 * </pre>
 *  
 * Notes:
 * <li>instantiate and use, it will reuse its own cache, so after a while it is supposed to run in O(1).
 *     Code is super fast (0.0ms)
 * <li>For very big numbers, use Stirling's approximation, @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
 * <li>Overflow is a big problem. 
 *     the max value is 9223372036854775807 < 21!, 
 *     1.7976931348623157E308 <171!
 *     Either it is super fast or it breaks, the combinations grow too fast, and for 2k~n it is biggest; 
 *     it cannot even handle (29 14) but for k/n small it can function barely.
 * 
 */
public class Factorial {

    static private HashMap<Integer, Double> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Double> (); 

    public Double factorial(int n)
    {
    Integer N = Integer.valueOf( n );
    if(cache.containsKey( N) ) return cache.get( N );

    if(n<1) {
        cache.put( N, 0D );
        return 0D;
    }
    if(n==1) {
        cache.put( N, 1D );
        return 1D;
    }

    Double temp = 1D;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        temp*=i;
        cache.put( i, temp );
    }

    Double prev = factorial(n-1);
    if(prev>Double.MAX_VALUE/n) throw new IllegalArgumentException("factorial("+n+") overflow");

    return n*prev;
    }

    // 52!/47! = 52*51*50*49*48 so extra(52,47) = 52*(51,47) ... and (47,47)=1
    private Double extra(int n, int minus)
    {
        if(n<=minus) return 1D;
        Double result = extra(n-1,minus);
        if(result>Double.MAX_VALUE/n) throw new IllegalArgumentException(  "overflow");
        return n* result;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * This method computes (n k) = n!/(k! * (n-k)!) 
     * <p/>
     * Example usage:
     * <li>over(52,2) = 2598960
     * <li>over(5,2) = 10
     * <li>over(2,2) = 1 //ignoring swaps
     *
     * @param n the big set
     * @param k how much to draw out of n
     * @return all combinations of drawing k out of n, ignoring swaps. Simply double the amount for regarding swaps.
     *
     */
    public Double over(int n, int k){
        if(k==n) return 1D;
        if(k>n) return 0D;
        if(k<=0) return 0D;
        //k>=1 and n>k
        if(k<n-k) return over(n,n-k); 
        Double over = extra(n,k);
        Double divisor = factorial(k);      
        return over/divisor;            
    }

    /**
     * basic test and usage
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Double fuc= new Factorial().factorial( 170);     //takes a while, because no cache yet
        System.out.println(fuc);


        {
            int n = 100;
            int k = 50;
            double start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            //Factorial f = new Factorial();
            Double ten_over_two = new Factorial().over(n,k);     //takes a while, because no cache yet
            double delta = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
            System.out.println( "ten_over_two=" +ten_over_two + ": in " + delta + "ms");
        }

      {
            int n = 8;
            double start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        Factorial f = new Factorial();
        System.out.println( f.factorial( n)); //instantaneous
            double delta = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;

            System.out.println( "factorial("+n+") in " + delta + "ms");
      }

    }

}//~class}
```

Comment: Why would that be faster ?

Comment: because it reuses already computed factors.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is but here goes. Let's assume you are trying to have a computer perform the calculation. 1M! would have an exponent of < 10^6M. Not sure about software out there for that large of an exponent. If you take the log to calculate then the number is just < 6M. Logs also have the advantage of being addition when multiplying, so doing a M of addition is not that big of a deal. You could also set the function to be between i and k which would speed things up, assuming a fairly large size of i. Additionally you could look up the value for 100K! (2.824229408 × 10 456573 the log of which is  456573.450899970914458) and then just iterate on values larger than that.